# Firebase profile after creating a user account

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

How do you get past the firebase rules, I done a similar thing but the rules are not allowing me to create an entry for users? So I added in the appropriate rules and now the permission error disappears. However it still does not create the entry

My Permissions

```
match /users/{userId} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
}
```

My Firebase code

```
firebase
  .auth()
  .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
  .then(() => {
    if (firebase.auth().currentUser) {
      db.collection('users')
        .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
        .set({
          email: this.email,
          fname: this.fname,
          lname: this.lname,
          user_id: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
        })
    }
  })
  .catch(err => {
    this.feedback = err.message
  })
}
```

Comment: Are there any logs in console?

Comment: The code looks fine for the rules you posted, so the problem is likely elsewhere. I recommend checking the logcat output of your app when this code runs for relevant information as you step through the code line by line in a debugger.